# Is there a way to include elements from html inside a class in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, css-selectors

I am working on a web scraping problem. I selected elements from HTML using css-selectors and I was wondering if it is possible to include them inside a class in Ruby:

```
name = browser.p(css: 'p[bo-bind="row.zName"]').text

account = browser.span(css: 'span[bo-bind="row.zAccount"]').text
```

Is there a way to declare name and account fields inside a class `Accounts`?

Something like this:

```
class Accounts @@name @@account
```

and then assign to those elements from HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking Ruby with HTML Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056486/linking-ruby-with-html-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code looks like this

```
name = browser.p(css: 'p[bo-bind="row.zName"]').text
account = browser.span(css: 'span[bo-bind="row.zAccount"]').text
```

You can encapsulate that in a class like so

```
class Account
  def initialize browser
    @name = browser.p(css: 'p[bo-bind="row.zName"]').text
    @account = browser.span(css: 'span[bo-bind="row.zAccount"]').text
  end
end

account = Account.new(browser)
```

Comment: Perfection! Thank you @Max!